# Read only first line of gzip JSON file

Tags: python, json, gzip

Although a lot of code has been posted here about how to read the first line of a file, I cannot figure out how to only read the first line of a gzipped JSON file in Python.

Here is my current working example. However, it contains a nasty `break` statement, and the loop seems completely unnecessary:

```py
for line in gzip.open(file, 'rb'):
    one_line = json.loads(line)
    print(one_line)
    break
```

Is there a solution that keeps the `json.loads()` command (or a similar one that reads in the JSON file correctly), while only reading the first line of the gzipped JSON file?

Comment: If the json goes over more lines reading only one line would end in not valid json. You have already the first line in `line`

Comment: is each line of the file a selfcontained json block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `readline()` instead of a `for` loop.

```
with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as f:
    line = f.readline()
one_line = json.loads(line)
print(one_line)
```